# Google script won't ask for authorization unless it is run in the script editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to attach a PDF of one sheet to an email, and have gotten it to work with the code below.  The problem is that it has to be run from the editor the first time or the authorization modal won't appear and the script just hangs.  I need to be able to run this script from the sheet itself.  Here is my code:

```
function spreadsheetToPDF(key, id, name) {

  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("spreadsheets");
  var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"

  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");  

  var requestData = {
    "oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
  };
  var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/a/propertysolutions.com/spreadsheets/d/"+key+ "/export?format=pdf&size=0&fzr=true&portrait=false&fitw=true&gid=" + id +
                "&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=true", requestData).getBlob().setName(name);

  return pdf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been discussed quite a few times, it can be found in the [issue tracker under ref 677](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&q=677&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&id=677) and the latest updates mention that it won't be fixed.

In the same time, one of the latest posts (by E. Koleda) suggests a different workflow (and promise to show examples in the near future).